# How can I RedirectToAction within $.ajax callback?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery

I use $.ajax() to poll an action method every 5 seconds as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', url: '/MyController/IsReady/1',
    dataType: 'json', success: function (xhr_data) {
        if (xhr_data.active == 'pending') {
            setTimeout(function () { ajaxRequest(); }, 5000);                  
        }
    }
});
```

and the ActionResult action:

```
public ActionResult IsReady(int id)
{
    if(true)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction");
    }
    return Json("pending");
}
```

I had to change the action return type to ActionResult in order to use RedirectToAction (originally it was JsonResult and I was returning `Json(new { active = 'active' };`), but it looks to have trouble redirecting and rendering the new View from within the $.ajax() success callback. I need to redirect to "AnotherAction" from within this polling ajax postback. Firebug's response is the View from "AnotherAction", but it's not rendering.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to consume the result of your ajax request and use that to run javascript to manually update window.location yourself.  For example, something like:

```
// Your ajax callback:
function(result) {
    if (result.redirectUrl != null) {
        window.location = result.redirectUrl;
    }
}
```

Where "result" is the argument passed to you by jQuery's ajax method after completion of the ajax request.  (And to generate the URL itself, use `UrlHelper.GenerateUrl`, which is an MVC helper that creates URLs based off of actions/controllers/etc.)

Comment: found something similar on another post after exhaustive searching. only difference was that it used window.location.replace instead. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a super old article but after scouring the web this was still the top answer on Google, and I ended up using a different solution. If you want to use a pure RedirectToAction this works as well. The RedirectToAction response contains the complete markup for the view.

**C#:**

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { myRouteValue = foo});
```

**JS:**

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./PostController/PostAction",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function (result) {
        if (result.responseText) {
            $('body').html(result.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

C# worked well

I just changed the JS because responseText was not working for me:

```js
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: posturl,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false,
        data: requestjson,
        success: function(result) {
            if (result) {
                $('body').html(result);
            }
        },

        error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4){
            var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
            if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you add the parametter "dataType: 'json'" to your request, you will get the required responseText variable in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Html.RenderAction` helper in a View:

```
public ActionResult IsReady(int id)
{
    if(true)
    {
        ViewBag.Action = "AnotherAction";
        return PartialView("_AjaxRedirect");
    }
    return Json("pending");
}
```

And in the "_AjaxRedirect" partial view:

```
@{
    string action = ViewBag.ActionName;
    Html.RenderAction(action);
}
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49137153/150342