# HTTP 303 redirect from XHR long poll does not redirect

Tags: javascript, http

I have a web interface that does long polling, ie every 10 seconds it updates some statuses on the webpage using an AJAX request on an interval. I am able to, on some condition, return a 303 redirect to "kick" the user from the page. It doesn't seem to work. Chrome/FireFox.

Looking at Chrome's Network tab

1. Browser opens page
2. Browser is requesting JSON data every 10 seconds
3. On next request, instead of a 200  with JSON data, a 303 is returned
4. The page to be redirected to appears as a request (200, xhr) but the browser does not redirect. It just carries on.

The 303 appears with the following

```
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Location: /kicked
```

The next request is immediately the kicked page, but it's in an XHR request instead of the browser redirecting there.

Comment: You need to pass the additional parameters `Location` to the header call.

Comment: I do. It is set.

Comment: You expect the browser to redirect on an XHR call??? The page is not going to update since it makes no sense for some XHR call to effect the page. You would have to build logic into your XHR response handler to do the redirect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I RedirectToAction within $.ajax callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534956/how-can-i-redirecttoaction-within-ajax-callback)

Comment: @epascarello Yes that's what I expected.

Comment: Well that is not what happens. The request changes, not the page.