# ASP.NET MVC: How do you verify entity ownership on edit action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes

in ASP.NET MVC application I want to verify entity ownership on edit action (already on get).
I have implemented custom IPrincipal, so I have actual user ID, but how to compare it with entity property?

The only way I see is to load the entity and compare it, which makes bunch of if conditions in every action method.

Ideal would be some attribute, but inside the attribute I have only the entity ID, not the entity itself and you can't pass any object (nor entity neither repository) to attribute.

How do you solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447297/asp-net-mvc-4-how-to-access-modify-the-view-model-object-and-change-view-and-a

Comment: Thanks, engaging thread, but that is not the way I guess. Because on GET Edit action you get only ID of business object (not the object itself) and you are not able to get the object values in attribute, nor you can't inject the repository.

Comment: Can you provide sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by extension method over the EntityBase implementing interface IOwnedEntity (with two properties: Id and OwnerId).
In this extension method I compare the IOwnedEntity.OwnerId with actual user Id (got from cookies) and if not equal I throw my own typed exception (NotAuthorizedException).

Comment: Are you still loading the entity from the DB to do the comparison? Can you provide some sample code? This is such a common requirement and best practice seems to be poorly documented on the web. I'm in the same situation and it seems that there is just a lot of trips to the DB which I'm hoping to avoid without compromising security.