# Is there a way to server.transfer from my MVC controller to another Webforms page in the same folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a site with some logic in an MVC project and other logic in an older webforms project.

Can I server.transfer from an mvc controller to a webforms page?
Or transfer in some other way?

Comment: `Response.Redirect("url")` is not enough?

Comment: I don't want to response.redirect because that's a round-trip back to the client.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799511/how-to-simulate-server-transfer-in-asp-net-mvc/892545#892545

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Redirect() method on a controller (which returns RedirectResult) but this will cause the return of HTTP 301 and a roundtrip to the server to the new location.

There is no Server.Transfer direct equivalent in MVC.

You could have used Html.RenderAction in your view, but it will be a bit nasty and requires your other action to be in MVC.