# Redirect without StatusCode

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an **Home** controller that has an Index Action that I'm not ready to implement it yet.

So, I decided to **redirect** it to the Index Action of the **Feed** controller. When I used online SEO analysis tools, they told me that my website is beeing found as "object moved".

The Feed/Index is OK but the root is indexed by search engines as "object moved" (probably 301?)

Can I make this redirection withou setting any Status Code?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking to transfer the request rather than redirect it (i.e. mvc equivalent of Server.Transfer)

There is a stackoverflow question/answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799511/how-to-simulate-server-transfer-in-asp-net-mvc) with a good answer which shows how to do this.