# Is it possible to retrieve a Controller instance for some Url string in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

if i have an route like `/foo/bar/pewpew` .. is it possible to get an instance of the controller which that route maps too?

Comment: should be... is `foo` your controller? could you define what each part of your url represents?

Comment: What do you mean with "return a controller" and what _is_ the controller in your example?

Comment: @Henk: Whatever ASP.Net would instantiate if you navigate to that URL.

Comment: Where are you planning to use this instance? the `MvcHandler` does the work of mapping the route values to a controller (which it requests via the `ControllerBuilder`/`DependencyResolver`). You user code really starts within a controller already, so what are you trying to do? A use case would be nice point to start.

Comment: @Matthew Abbot : custom error handling. Previous SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972521/how-do-i-execute-a-controller-action-from-an-httpmodule-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the controller name, you can call create a fake `HttpContextBase` that returns your URL in its `Request`, then pass it to `RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData` and check the `area` and `controller` values.

To get the controller instance, pass a `RequestContext` consisting of that `HttpContextBase` and `RouteData` to `ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory.CreateController`.

Comment: creating a fake `HttpContextBase` :: which (bare minimum) properties will I need to override for `GetRouteData` to not throw an exception? (and the rest of the answer makes sense).

Comment: Hmmm .. not sure why it was removing the @SLaks word from my previous comment... ??

Comment: @Pure: You don't need to `@`-address the person who wrote the post you're commenting on.

Comment: @Pure:I think all you need is `Request.Url`.  Try it and see if you get an exception.

Comment: Looking at the source, you only need `AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath` and `PathInfo`, as well as any properties used by custom `IRouteConstraint`s.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
        var wrapper=new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
        var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(wrapper);
        var controller = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(new RequestContext(wrapper, routeData), routeData.Values["controller"].ToString());
```

Update, you can use this instead.

```
var wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(new System.Web.HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "http://localhost:4836/", null), new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())));
```

Comment: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` might not be the url i wish to use. In fact, it will never be the correct url in my scenario's.