# HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer null when changing domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi have a website that is host on 2 servers, on in Europe for the french version of the website (.fr) and the other in the Us for the other versions (.com). When I do a RedirectResult("http://domain.fr") from my .com website in a controller, my Referrer is null is it normal?

I think that I will have to post a querystring from a domain to an other so I will be able to know when it's comming from this site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate Server.Transfer in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799511/how-to-simulate-server-transfer-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @Yahia it's not the same thing since with the other post solution I can't transfer from a domain to an other

Answer (score 0):

urlreferrer is collected from the client side browser

are you make sure that your test request site A from a link in Site B and not response.redirect

Comment: it's not from a link and it's not a response.redirect, it's using MVC so it's a RedirectResult()

Comment: sorry, i did not read you post well, but I think RedirectResult() not affect on the browser to store paramters like urlreferrer ... Good luck