# NullReferenceException while storing data to session in an ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, controller

I have a following View Method in an ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller that retrieves data from Amazon SimpleDb, stores it in a list and then stores that list object in a session. But at the line where I am storing the userBox object in a session (Session["userBox"] = userBox), I am getting a NullReferenceException. I am sure that userBox is not null. Even if I try to store a simple string in a session (like Session["userBox"] = "test") I still get NullReferenceException.

Here is the code:

```
  public ActionResult SetSidebarAccountBoxSessions(string id)
    {
        string selectExpression = "select * from MySimpleDBDomain where itemName()='" + id + "'";

        SelectRequest sreq = new SelectRequest().WithSelectExpression(selectExpression);

        SelectResponse sres = sdb.Select(sreq);

        List<User> userBox = new List<User>();



        if (sres.IsSetSelectResult())
        {
            SelectResult selectresult = sres.SelectResult;

            foreach (Item item in selectresult.Item)
            {

                string a = item.Name;


                userBox.Add(new User
                {


                    imageThug = item.Attribute[0].Value,
                    name = item.Attribute[3].Value,
                    bio = item.Attribute[1].Value



                });

            }
        }

        Session["userBox"] = userBox;

        return View();


    }
```

I am calling this SetSideBarAccountBoxSessions(id) method from another controller method:

```
 HomeController hc = new HomeController();
hc.SetSidebarAccountBoxSessions(item.Name);
```

Can this be the problem? Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: If you check `Session` just before the `Session["userBox"] = userBox;` line, is it `null`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is related to the fact that you create HomeController by yourself. You can try to use `TransferToRouteResult` to transfer the action to HomeController.

You an find the code of `TransferToRouteResult` in this link:

[How to simulate Server.Transfer in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799511/how-to-simulate-server-transfer-in-asp-net-mvc)