# TransferToAction?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, redirecttoaction

`RedirectoToAction` is a client side operation. Not only is it voluntary, any data that is to be passed has to make a round trip, and is exposed in the query string.  The latter somewhat goes against "clean" urls as one of the good points of `ASP.NET MVC.`

Is there the equivalent of `Server.Transfer`?

Comment: See the following post for the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799511/how-to-simulate-server-transfer-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thanks!  Just what I was looking for.  How do I mark yours as the answer?

Comment: No need to, just flag it as a great comment if you think it deserves it.