# Faking MVC Server.Transfer: Response.End() does not end my thread

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, server.transfer

I have two issues here, the second one is irrelevant if the first one got answered, but still technically interesting in my opinion... I will try to be as clear as possible:

- 1st question: my goal is to fake a Server.Transfer in MVC, is there any descent way to do that, I found quite a few articles about it, but most where about redirecting / rerouting, which is not possible in my case (not that I can think of at least).

Here is the context, we have two versions of our website, a "desktop" one and a mobile one. Our marketing guy wants both versions of the home page to be served on the same url (because the SEO expert said so).

This sounds trivial and simple, and it kind of is in most cases, except... Our desktop site is a .NET 4.0 ASPX site, and our mobile site is MVC, both run in the same site (same project, same apppool, same app).

Because the desktop version represents about 95% of our traffic, this should be the default, and we want to "transfer" (hence same url) from the ASPX code behind to the MVC view only if user is on a mobile device or really wants to see the mobile version. As far as I saw so far, there is no easy way to do that (Server.Transfer only executes a new handler - hence page - if there is a physical file for it). Hence question has any one done that in a proper way so far?

And which brings me to:

- 2nd question: I did build my own transfer to MVC mechanism, but then figured out that a Response.End() does not actually ends the running thread anymore, does anyone have a clue why?

Obviously, I don't expect any answer out of the blue, so here is what I am doing:

in the page(s) which needs transfering to mobile, I do something like:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnPreInit(e);
  MobileUri = "/auto/intro/index"; // the MVC url to transfer to
  //Identifies correct flow based on certain conditions 1-Desktop 2-Mobile
  BrowserCheck.RedirectToMobileIfRequired(MobileUri);
}
```

and my actual TransferToMobile method called by RedirectToMobileIfRequired (I skipped the detection part as it is quite irrelevant) looks like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Does a transfer to the mobile (MVC) action. While keeping the same url.
/// </summary>
private static void TransferToMobile(string uri) {
  var cUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;

  // build an absolute url from relative uri passed as parameter
  string url = String.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}", cUrl.Scheme, cUrl.Authority, uri.TrimStart('/'));

  // fake a context for the mvc redirect (in order to read the routeData).
  var fakeContext = new HttpContextWrapper(new HttpContext(new HttpRequest("", url, ""), HttpContext.Current.Response));
  var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(fakeContext);

  // get the proper controller
  IController ctrl = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(fakeContext.Request.RequestContext, (string)routeData.Values["controller"]);

  // We still need to set routeData in the request context, as execute does not seem to use the passed route data.
  HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["Area"] = routeData.DataTokens["Area"];
  HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = routeData.Values["controller"];
  HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = routeData.Values["action"];

  // Execute the MVC controller action
  ctrl.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), routeData));

  if (ctrl is IDisposable) {
    ((IDisposable)ctrl).Dispose(); // does not help
  }

  // end the request.
  HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
  // fakeContext.Response.End(); // does not add anything
  // HttpContext.Current.Response.Close(); // does not help
  // fakeContext.Response.Close(); // does not help
  // Thread.CurrentThread.Abort(); // causes infinite loading in FF
}
```

At this point, I would expect the Response.End() call to end the thread as well (and it does if I skip the whole faking the controller execution bit) but it doesn't.

I therefore suspect that either my faked context (was the only way I found to be able to passed my current context with a new url) or the controller prevents the thread to be killed.

fakeContext.Response is same as CurrentContext.Response, and the few attempts at ending the fake context's response or killing the thread didn't really help me.

Whatever code is running after the Response.End() will NOT actually be rendered to the client (which is a small victory), as the Response stream (and the connection, no "infinite loading" in the client) is being closed. But code is still running and that is no good (also obviously generates loads of errors when trying to write the ASPX page, write headers, etc.).

So any new lead would be more than welcome!

To sum it up: 
- does anyone have a less hacky way to achieve sharing a ASPX page and a MVC view on the same url?
- if not, does anyone have a clue how I can ensure that my Response is really being ended?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The "SEO Expert" said the most common and globaly accepted partern to run a mobile version of a site is not a good thing? Awesome!

Comment: +1 for content; extra +1 for the sarcasm

Comment: @Pluc: indeed, gave my opinion here, SEO expert is more expensive, he wins :). But anyway, unfortunately not every helpful in my scenario (unless you charge more for your services as a SEO expert of course). Thx for stating the obvious nevertheless :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

for whoever is interested, I at least have answer to question 1 :).
When I first worked on that feature, I looked at the following (and very close) question:

[How to simulate Server.Transfer in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799511/how-to-simulate-server-transfer-in-asp-net-mvc)

And tried both the Transfer Method created by Stan (using *httpHandler.ProcessRequest*) and *Server.TransferRequest* methods. Both had desadvantages for me:

- the first one does not work in IIS, (because I need to call that in a page, and that seems too late already).
- the second one makes it terribly annoying for developers who all need to run their site in IIS (no biggy, but still...).

Seeing that my solution obviously wasn't optimal, I had to come back to the IIS solution, which seems to be the neatest for production environment.

This solution worked for a page and triggered an infinite loop on another one...

That's when I got pointed to what I had lazily discarded as not being the cause: our url redirect module. It uses Request.RawUrl to match a rule, and oh surprise, **Server.TransferRequest keeps the original Request.RawUrl, while app.Request.Url.AbsolutePath will contain the transfered-to url.** So basically our url rewrite module was always redirecting to the original requested which was trying to transfer to the new one, etc.

Changed that in the url rewriting module, and will hope that everything still works like a charm (obviously a lot of testing will follow such a change)...

In order to fix the developers issue, I chose to combine both solutions, which might make it a bit more of a risk for different behaviors between development and production, but that's what we have test servers for...

so here is my transfer method looks like in the end:

**Once again this is meant to transfer from an ASPX page to a MVC action, from MVC to MVC  you probably don't need anything that complex, as you can use a TransferResult or just return a different view, call another action, etc.**

```
private static void Transfer(string url) {
  if (HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline) {
    // IIS 7 integrated pipeline, does not work in VS dev server.
    HttpContext.Current.Server.TransferRequest(url, true);
  }

  // for VS dev server, does not work in IIS
  var cUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
  // Create URI builder
  var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(cUrl.Scheme, cUrl.Host, cUrl.Port, HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
  // Add destination URI
  uriBuilder.Path += url;
  // Because UriBuilder escapes URI decode before passing as an argument
  string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(uriBuilder.Uri.PathAndQuery);
  // Rewrite path
  HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(path, true);
  IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
  // Process request
  httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much research, but here's what seems to be happening upon `Response.End()`:

```
public void End()
{
    if (this._context.IsInCancellablePeriod)
    {
        InternalSecurityPermissions.ControlThread.Assert();
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort(new HttpApplication.CancelModuleException(false));
    }
    else if (!this._flushing)
    {
        this.Flush();
        this._ended = true;
        if (this._context.ApplicationInstance != null)
        {
            this._context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

That could at least provide the "Why" (`_context.IsInCancellablePeriod`). You could try to trace that using your favourite CLR decompiler.