# How to execute controller actions that return Views but keep the URL intact in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, controller, action

When I navigate to /Controller/Action in ASP.NET MVC, the action returns a View and the browser URL is updated. How could I keep the URL intact but return the requested View at the same time?

For example, /Home/Index would return the View for Index whereas /Home/SignUp would return a different View. I want to make sure after both calls, the URL stays the same.

Comment: In your words, and in web, "call" means requesting resource by specifying "url". There are no "both calls" if there's single url. You could use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to request resources from server without updating page and url

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly specify the view you want to return in the controller action:

```
return View("~/Views/SomeController/SomeView.cshtml");
```

Comment: I don't think that would execute the action method though. I think it would simply return the View. I'm setting ViewBag properties in the action.

Comment: No, this will not execute the action. Since you will be returning a different view you could set the required ViewBag properties in this action.

Answer (score 0):

These would be GET calls and this behaviour is intrinsic.

If you want to stay on the same page or even have a [single page application](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application) then you need to consider using ajax and http POST to get the different views you need to build up your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by performing several approaches:

**1. Configure your route config**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: null,
                url: "Home/FirstMethod",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "FirstMethod" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: null,
                url: "Home/SecondMethod",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "FirstMethod" }
            );
```

**2. Using custom MVCTransferResult:**
[How to simulate Server.Transfer in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799511/how-to-simulate-server-transfer-in-asp-net-mvc/1242525#1242525)

**3. You can specifiy view explictly,
for example:**

```
return View(viewName: "Contact");
```