# Access to url from within an mvc project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

Is it possible to configure the route within a asp.net mvc project when redirecting to an external url?

for example

```
public ActionResult MyUrl()
{
    return Redirect("http://www.myurl.com/");
}
```

I dont want the the url of `http://www.myurl.com/` to be displayed in the address bar but

```
MyProject/MyUrl
```

I tried this

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "MyUrl", new { controller = "Home", action = "MyUrl" });
```

Comment: You need to make "transfer", look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799511/how-to-simulate-server-transfer-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I think Server.TransferRequest has replaced transfer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344901(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For external URL you could not use `Server.TransferRequest`. This method just works for same site. Use `iframe` to your view instead:

```
public ActionResult MyUrl()
{
    return View();
}
```

In your view use `iframe` with external URL:

```
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.myurl.com/"></iframe>
</body>
```

By using this method user see `MyProject/MyUrl` in the address bar. But keep in mind user could easily discover actual URL by viewing source of HTML file.