# Zen barcode render with mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, barcode

I am using Zen barcode framework with MVC, The barcode is rendering just fine but due to adding a new route for to support the barcode in the Route.config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
         Allow extensionless handling of barcode image URIs
        routes.Add(
            "BarcodeImaging",
            new Route(
               "Barcode/{id}",new BarcodeImageRouteHandler()));

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
```

The problem is my action link URLs don't work correctly anymore, they use the barcode route config instead of the default MVC routing

My action Links

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "RequestTests",new { id=item.RequestTestID },null) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Invoice", "Details", new { id=item.RequestTestID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.RequestTestID })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have extended the wrong part of MVC to handle routing. [`IRouteHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.iroutehandler(v=vs.110).aspx) can only handle *incoming* URLs.

Instead, you should subclass [`RouteBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routebase(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Route`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route(v=vs.110).aspx), which are capable of handling both incoming *and outgoing* URLs. `RouteBase` has two methods to override

1. [`GetRouteData(HttpContextBase)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routebase.getroutedata(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle incoming requests (typically converts a URL to a dictionary of route values)
2. [`GetVirtualPath(RequestContext, RouteValueDictionary)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routebase.getvirtualpath(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle outgoing requests (typically converts a dictionary of route values to a URL)

In addition, each of these methods must return `null` when the route *does not match* the current request to ensure the routing framework will attempt to match all subsequent routes in the route table. This implies that its also the route's job to determine if the route matches the request (which can be done with an `if` statement).

The [`UrlHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx) class and all extension methods that use it, such as [`ActionLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx) all use the `GetVirtualPath()` method to build URLs, so you must implement it if you want any of these methods to work.

### Custom RouteBase Examples

- [Multiple levels in MVC custom routing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31934144)
- [Creating Custom RouteBase class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762350/creating-custom-routebase-class)
- [Customizing Routes in ASP.NET MVC – Custom RouteBase implementations](http://www.devcurry.com/2013/05/customizing-routes-in-aspnet-mvc-custom.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
        routes.Add(
            "BarcodeImaging",
            new Route(
                "Barcode/{barcodeId}",
                new BarcodeImageRouteHandler()));
```

Works fine for me