# Is there something like "RewriteToAction"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Knowing [`RedirectToAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction), I was looking for something similar to keep the URL stable for the user and still pass responsibility from one action to another.

Since I found [zero Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22RewriteToAction%22) on this topic, I might as well completely try to solve an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Still, I'll try to explain why I believe there might be a need for this.

**Scenario:**

```cs
public ActionResult A(int id)
{
    var uniqueID = CalculateUniqueFromId(id);

    // This compiles.
    return RedirectToAction("B", new { uniqueID });

    // This does not compile.
    return RewriteToAction("B", new { uniqueID });
}

public ActionResult B(Guid uniqueID)
{
    var model = DoCreateModelForUnique(uniqueID);
    return View("B", model);
}
```

In above code, action A calculates a guid from an integer and passes it to another action.

**Workaround:**

I could change the above code to something like this:

```cs
public ActionResult A(int id)
{
    var uniqueID = CalculateUniqueFromId(id);
    var model = DoCreateModelForUnique(uniqueID);

    return View("B", model);
}

public ActionResult B(Guid uniqueID)
{
    var model = DoCreateModelForUnique(uniqueID);
    return View("B", model);
}
```

This would work as expected.

Still, in more complex scenarios, I would love to have a "server-side redirect" (aka rewrite) to use every now and then.

**Alternative workaround:**

I also could use [`HttpContext.RewritePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath), e.g. inside Global.asax's `Application_BeginRequest` to do a rewrite.

This feels to me "out of the MVC context", even though it works as expected.

**My question:**

Is there an elegant, MVC-integrated way of doing something like `RewriteToAction`?

**Update 1:**

[Luke commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467215/is-there-something-like-rewritetoaction#comment73989961_43467215) a promising link:

> [How to simulate Server.Transfer in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799511/107625)

I'll try to investigate, whether this fits my needs.

Comment: I don't suppose that this would fulfill your requirements?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1180744/894792 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/1242525/894792

Comment: That looks very promising, @Luke, I'll take a look, thanks a lot .

Comment: Good luck my friend! :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
public ActionResult A(int id)
{
    var uniqueID = CalculateUniqueFromId(id);

    return B(uniqueID);
}

public ActionResult B(Guid uniqueID)
{
    var model = DoCreateModelForUnique(uniqueID);
    return View("B", model);
}
```

?

Comment: Simply calling the action method. That looks neat. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. If it works for you, can you accept the answer please? Thanks

Comment: Sure! I'll try to wait another few days, to possible get another feedback.