# MVC5 server-side redirect using filterContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have a table with url redirects and previously I was using `HttpModule` approach to query the db and handle redirects, if such are found. However now I want to redesign this functionality in `ActionFilter` for two reasons:

1. `HttpModule` handles all requests, while I only need redirects at certain types of content. In all other cases this results in a pointless db query.
2. I need additional feature - to use **301 client-side redirect** on certain conditions and default to **server-side redirect** for the rest.

Currently in my `HttpModule` I am using `HttpContext.RewritePath` to implement the **server-side redirect**. My question is how can I achieve the same result in `ActionFilter`.

To clarify **server-side redirect**: I want to be able to access the same content from two different links. If `courses/programming-basics/details` (verbal url) is redirected to `/course/{id}/details` (real action path), I want to be able to use the verbal url to access this content.

Currently, using the `ActionExecutingContext` I am using

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url)
```

which results in **301 client-side**.

**Clarification**: I want to have my content being accessible via the old urls. Following the above example This results in a single page that presents identical content with two valid urls: `courses/programming-basics/details` and `course/{id}/details. Perhaps I am using redirects incorrectly, but that is how I managed to phrase my question.

Comment: Just setup a proper routing for your actions and you'll be fine. No IIS modules or action filters required.

Comment: Server redirects appear to be non-trivial in MVC, but can be done: https://stackoverflow.com/q/799511/728795. But @haim770 is right - you might be able to just resolve this with routing too

Comment: @alex what 301 client side redirect means ?, It's happening from server side.

Comment: @haim770 I am not sure what "proper routing" means. Rewriting all routes is not an option, since we are talking about a medium to large scale app. The `url redirects` are required for backwards compatibility, plus the old urls are very human-readable, which is a plus for marketing.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, its happening from server. However, 301 response contains the redirected location. Then the client performs another request to the desired Url. I've seen this referred as client-side redirect. Not sure if it is completely semantically correct.

Comment: @Alex see https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection only 301 is used for a permanent redirect. look like this is how it works.

Comment: @Adrian that may be, but this way my fake url only points to the real one. I want both urls to display the same content (which is contained behind the real one). This way the users can see verbal urls.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem here, as suggested by @Andrei. This line was enough:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Server.TransferRequest(url);
```

This returned the correct content and kept the old, verbose url. Exactly what I needed.